# How can I access the values in Authors?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Well, I have to list the authors with their books and the amount of the their reviews and I have to write it in XML format with the help of LINQ.

Here is the data (only the part where the books, authors and reviews are, is important)

```
static public class SampleData
  {
    static public Publisher[] Publishers =
    {
      new Publisher {Name="FunBooks"},
      new Publisher {Name="Joe Publishing"},
      new Publisher {Name="I Publisher"}
    };

    static public Author[] Authors =
    {
      new Author {FirstName="Johnny", LastName="Good"},
      new Author {FirstName="Graziella", LastName="Simplegame"},
      new Author {FirstName="Octavio", LastName="Prince"},
      new Author {FirstName="Jeremy", LastName="Legrand"}
    };

    static public Subject[] Subjects =
    {
      new Subject {Name="Software development",Description="developing and others"},
      new Subject {Name="Novel",Description="great feelings"},
      new Subject {Name="Science fiction",Description="out of space and everywhere"}
    };

    static public Book[] Books =
    {
      new Book {                                        // [0]
        Title="Funny Stories",
        Publisher=Publishers[0],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[0], Authors[1]},
        PageCount=101,
        Price=25.55M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(2004, 11, 10),
        Isbn="0-000-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[0]
      },
      new Book {                                        // [1]
        Title="LINQ rules",
        Publisher=Publishers[1],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[2]},
        PageCount=300,
        Price=12M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(2007, 9, 2),
        Isbn="0-111-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[0]
      },
      new Book {                                        // [2]
        Title="C# on Rails",
        Publisher=Publishers[1],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[2]},
        PageCount=256,
        Price=35.5M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(2007, 4, 1),
        Isbn="0-222-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[0]
      },
      new Book {                                        // [3]
        Title="All your base are belong to us",
        Publisher=Publishers[1],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[3]},
        PageCount=1205,
        Price=35.5M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(2006, 5, 5),
        Isbn="0-333-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[2]
      },
      new Book {                                        // [4]
        Title="Bonjour mon Amour",
        Publisher=Publishers[0],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[1], Authors[2]},
        PageCount=50,
        Price=29M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(1973, 2, 18),
        Isbn="2-444-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[1]
      }
    };

    static public User[] Users = 
    {
        new User{Name="Fred"},
        new User{Name="Barney"},
        new User{Name="Wilma"}
    };

    static public Review[] Reviews =
    {
        new Review{ Book = Books[0], Comments="cc1", Rating=2, User=Users[0]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[0], Comments="cc2", Rating=3, User=Users[2]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[1], Comments="cc3", Rating=1, User=Users[0]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[1], Comments="cc4", Rating=2, User=Users[1]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[1], Comments="cc5", Rating=1, User=Users[2]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[2], Comments="cc6", Rating=3, User=Users[2]},        
        new Review{ Book = Books[3], Comments="cc7", Rating=4, User=Users[2]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[4], Comments="cc8", Rating=5, User=Users[1]}
    };

    static SampleData()
    {
        // Books -- Reviews haben einnen Doppelverweise
        //          daher kann erst hier  Book-->Review gesetzt werden
        Books[0].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[0], Reviews[1] };
        Books[1].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[2], Reviews[3], Reviews[4] };
        Books[2].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[5] };
        Books[3].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[6] };
        Books[4].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[7] };
    }

  }
```

Here is what I've written (I can only print the authors)

```
var elements2 = new XElement("Autoren", SampleData.Authors
                .GroupBy(g => (g.FirstName + " " + g.LastName))
                .Select(g => new XElement("Autor", new XAttribute("Name", g.Key)))
                );

            var xml2 = new XElement("AuthorReviews", elements2);
            Console.WriteLine(xml2);
```

And it should look like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQS2q.png

Generally, my problem is, that I actually can only print the authors (if I use `SampleData.Authors`), but when I want to use `SampleData.Books` I don't know how to access the values in Authors (the part where it stands "new[]{Authors[..]}" is confusing me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication176
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XElement autoren = new XElement("Autoren");

            foreach (Author author in SampleData.Authors)
            {
                string fullName = author.FirstName + " " + author.LastName;
                XElement autor = new XElement("Author", new XAttribute("Name", fullName));
                autoren.Add(autor);
                foreach(Book book in SampleData.Books.Where(x => x.Authors.Any(y => y.FirstName + " " + y.LastName == fullName)))
                {
                    XElement xBook = new XElement("Buch", new object[] {new XAttribute("Title", book.Title), new XAttribute("Anzreviews", book.Reviews.Average(x => x.Rating))});
                    autor.Add(xBook);
                }
            }
  
        }
    }
    public class Publisher
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Author
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Subject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    public class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
        public Author[] Authors { get; set; }
        public int PageCount { get; set; }
        public decimal  Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
        public string Isbn { get; set; }
        public Subject Subject { get; set; }
        public Review[] Reviews { get; set; }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Review
    {
        public Book Book { get;set;}
        public string Comments {get;set;}
        public int Rating { get;set;}
        public User User { get;set;}
    }

    static public class SampleData
    {
        static public Publisher[] Publishers =
        {
          new Publisher {Name="FunBooks"},
          new Publisher {Name="Joe Publishing"},
          new Publisher {Name="I Publisher"}
        };

        static public Author[] Authors =
        {
          new Author {FirstName="Johnny", LastName="Good"},
          new Author {FirstName="Graziella", LastName="Simplegame"},
          new Author {FirstName="Octavio", LastName="Prince"},
          new Author {FirstName="Jeremy", LastName="Legrand"}
        };

        static public Subject[] Subjects =
        {
          new Subject {Name="Software development",Description="developing and others"},
          new Subject {Name="Novel",Description="great feelings"},
          new Subject {Name="Science fiction",Description="out of space and everywhere"}
        };

        static public Book[] Books =
        {
          new Book {                                        // [0]
            Title="Funny Stories",
            Publisher=Publishers[0],
            Authors=new[]{Authors[0], Authors[1]},
            PageCount=101,
            Price=25.55M,
            PublicationDate=new DateTime(2004, 11, 10),
            Isbn="0-000-77777-2",
            Subject=Subjects[0]
          },
          new Book {                                        // [1]
            Title="LINQ rules",
            Publisher=Publishers[1],
            Authors=new[]{Authors[2]},
            PageCount=300,
            Price=12M,
            PublicationDate=new DateTime(2007, 9, 2),
            Isbn="0-111-77777-2",
            Subject=Subjects[0]
          },
          new Book {                                        // [2]
            Title="C# on Rails",
            Publisher=Publishers[1],
            Authors=new[]{Authors[2]},
            PageCount=256,
            Price=35.5M,
            PublicationDate=new DateTime(2007, 4, 1),
            Isbn="0-222-77777-2",
            Subject=Subjects[0]
          },
          new Book {                                        // [3]
            Title="All your base are belong to us",
            Publisher=Publishers[1],
            Authors=new[]{Authors[3]},
            PageCount=1205,
            Price=35.5M,
            PublicationDate=new DateTime(2006, 5, 5),
            Isbn="0-333-77777-2",
            Subject=Subjects[2]
          },
          new Book {                                        // [4]
            Title="Bonjour mon Amour",
            Publisher=Publishers[0],
            Authors=new[]{Authors[1], Authors[2]},
            PageCount=50,
            Price=29M,
            PublicationDate=new DateTime(1973, 2, 18),
            Isbn="2-444-77777-2",
            Subject=Subjects[1]
          }
        };

        static public User[] Users = 
        {
            new User{Name="Fred"},
            new User{Name="Barney"},
            new User{Name="Wilma"}
        };

        static public Review[] Reviews =
        {
            new Review{ Book = Books[0], Comments="cc1", Rating=2, User=Users[0]},
            new Review{ Book = Books[0], Comments="cc2", Rating=3, User=Users[2]},
            new Review{ Book = Books[1], Comments="cc3", Rating=1, User=Users[0]},
            new Review{ Book = Books[1], Comments="cc4", Rating=2, User=Users[1]},
            new Review{ Book = Books[1], Comments="cc5", Rating=1, User=Users[2]},
            new Review{ Book = Books[2], Comments="cc6", Rating=3, User=Users[2]},        
            new Review{ Book = Books[3], Comments="cc7", Rating=4, User=Users[2]},
            new Review{ Book = Books[4], Comments="cc8", Rating=5, User=Users[1]}
        };

        static SampleData()
        {
            // Books -- Reviews haben einnen Doppelverweise
            //          daher kann erst hier  Book-->Review gesetzt werden
            Books[0].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[0], Reviews[1] };
            Books[1].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[2], Reviews[3], Reviews[4] };
            Books[2].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[5] };
            Books[3].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[6] };
            Books[4].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[7] };
        }

    }

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What an unusual database layout you have!

Before you create serious software with this, consider to create primary keys and foreign keys, and to implement proper one-to-many table relations and many-to-many table relations.

If you don't have a any idea what I'm talking about, ask your project leader for some time to study basic database ideas. It will pay off in the future.

So you have a sequence of `Books`, each `Book` has one or more `Authors`, and each Book has zero more Reviews. The Authors are already in your Books, but you decided to put the review in a separate table

> I have to list the authors with their books and the amount of the their reviews

Are Authors who haven't written any book yet, still Authors? Or do you only want Authors that have written at least one Book? Are there Authors in your Books list that are not in your Authors list? Are the Authors in your Authors list unique, or do you have several different Authors with the same first name and last name?

To transform the original "Books with their Authors" into "Authors with their Books" is not difficult

I'm not sure about "the amount of the their reviews". Do you mean the number of reviews these authors have for all their books, or the number of reviews they have per book? And do you only want the number of reviews, not the rating?

Normally if you have items with their zero or more subItems, like Teachers with their Students, and you want to reverse this, so Students with their Teachers, you use SelectMany to flatten the Teachers with their Students into combinations of one Teacher and one Student, and then GroupBy Student to get the Student with their Teachers.

So first we flatten "Books with their Authors" into [Book, Author] combinations, then we groupby Author:

```
var result = books.SelectMany(book => book.Author)
```

Input:

- Book A with Authors 1, 2
- Book B with Authors 3
- Book C with Authors 1, 3

After SelectMany: [A, 1], [A, 2], [B, 3], [C,1], [C, 3]

Continue the LINQ: GroupBy Authors:

```
.GroupBy(authorBookCombination => authorBookCombination.Author,

    // parameter resultSelector: take every Author, with all his Books, to create one new
    (author, booksOfThisAuthor) => new 
    {
        // Select only the Author properties that you want to save
        FirstName = author.FirstName,
        LastName = author.LastName,

        Books = booksOfThisAuthor.Select(book => new
        {
            // select only the Book properties that you want to save:
            Title = book.Title,
            Comments = book.Comments,
            ... // etc

            // don't Add the Authors!
            // TODO: "amount" of Reviews
        }
```

This was the easy part: get the Authors with their Books. If you also want the Authors that haven't written anything yet, start with the Author table and find for each Author his zero or more Books:

```
var result = Authors.Select(author => new
{
    FirstName = author.FirstName,
    LastName = author.LastName,

    Books = Books.Where(book => book.Author.Any(bookAuthor => bootkAuthor == author))
    .Select(book => new
    {
        Title = book.Title,
        ...
        // TODO reviews
    })
    .ToList(),
})
```

In words: from every Author in the table of Authors, get his first name and his last name. Get all Books that have at least one Author equal to this Author, and select several properties from these Books.

Now to get the Amount of Reviews for each Book, put in the Select where I wrote TODO:

```
ReviewAmount = reviews.Where(review => review.Book == book).Count(),
```

In words: for every Book that we take for this Author, check the table or reviews. Every Review is about a Book. Keep only those reviews that have a Book equal to the book we are creating.

If you want something more than just the Amount or Reviews:

```
ReviewInformation = reviews.Where(review => review.Book == book)
     .Select(review => new
     {
         Rating = review.Rating,
         Comments = review.Comments,
     })
     .ToList(),
```

Note that ReviewInformation.Count is the amount of Reviews that you originally asked for.

The result is a sequence of Authors, each Author with his zero or more Books, and each Book with (the Amount of ) its zero or more Reviews.

Now that you've got this, you can serialize it as XML using the XMLSerializer.